# Can't login with root at Runlevel 3

Tags: login

i used init 3 to move to runlevel 3 , but after I can't login with root password , i viewed the the file "/var/log/secure" and found this :

> Jun 25 17:39:12 localhost login: pam_unix(login:auth): authentication
> failure; logname=LOGIN uid=0 euid=0 tty=tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=root
> Jun 25 17:39:13 localhost login: FAILED LOGIN SESSION FROM (null) FOR
> root, Permission denied

what could be the issue ?

Regards

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/596695/centos-pam-unable-to-open-etc-pam-d-system-auth

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: You could have broken the PAM configuration as well. Only you know what you've done to your system.

Answer (score -1):

For all the people who had the same problem setting the SELinux to permissive  fixed the problem just run:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

and now I can log in to runlevel 3

Regards

Comment: So it was a SeLinux issue after all. `restorecon -rv /` or `touch /.autorelabel` should have solved it. Running without SeLinux is not recommended.